# R Markdown to Word: How to use minus-sign instead of hyphen?

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown

I am using a Windows computer in Germany and want to write down my analyses for an English audience. However, when I knit my Markdown file to Word, I always get hyphens instead of minus signs.

I know about the `signs` package. However, I don't want to use a function for every number I use in my file.

I also tried changing the regional format ("Time & language" -> "Language & region" -> "Regional format" and "Country or region") on my computer, but that didn't work either. (Yes, I tried restarting my computer too.)

How can I change that?

Example Markdown code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: word_document
---


```{r settings, include = FALSE}
# Global options  ####
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE,
                          message = FALSE,
                          results = "asis",
                          error = FALSE,
                          warning = FALSE,
                          st_options = "rmarkdown")
```

```{r }
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")  
cat(Sys.getlocale(), "\n\n")
cat(-10)
```


```{r }
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English_United States.1252-8")  # To convert the hyphen to minus sign!
cat(Sys.getlocale(), "\n\n")
cat(-10)
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strong believe that your only option is to use the `signs` package.

[Pandoc has a feature request to use the minus sign](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/8828) and the proposal says

> Negative numbers are typically typed by prepending `-`, though this symbol is primarily a hyphen and only secondarily a minus sign, and it is typically rendered as a hyphen. This due to the fact that ASCII has no dedicated minus sign, and consequently programming languages and other numerical software packages have adopted the hyphen as minus, long before Unicode introduced a dedicated minus.